# How to make thumbnails of uploaded animated gifs NOT animated

Tags: images, thumbnails

I am having an issue where I want the thumbnails of my animated gifs to NOT be animated. I tried to talk to hostgator about helping with this issue and they simply said that I must find a solution through wordpress to make this happen.

I run an adult site http://www.azngirls.com (please do not click if adult content is an issue for you) and as you can see, on the front page all the thumbnails of the animated gifs are all animated even after being resized into thumbnails and its creating a lot of lag for people that visit the site.

This site shows an example of how an uploaded gif should be shown - http://ipinpro.ericulous.com/pin/category/architecture/ - on the top right you can see a thumbnail of a GIF that is not animated, but when you click the image to view the original image, you can see that the animation appears. This is basically what I want happening for my site.

Comment: The GIFs are not resized. What image library are you using?

Comment: I just checked and GD and Image Magick are both available. What can I do to fix this issue? Didn't realise that it wasn't resizing at all lol.

Comment: Is there a registered thumbnail size for your use case? If the uploaded image is larger, a resize using just the first frame could be implemented.

Comment: That is what i would like for the site, exactly that. I'm not sure what you mean by registered thumbnail size for my use case though. 

How can I go about doing what you just mentioned?

Comment: Something like `set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 999 );` in your theme’s `functions.php`.

Comment: What does that do, in a bit more detail, if you don't mind! :D

Comment: See the [Codex for an introduction](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails).

Comment: I added that to functions.php it didn't work, any idea why? or maybe another fix?

Comment: I found a plugin called ImageMagick Engine and now things are actually getting resized. However, the issue now is that some gifs are not being resized and some of them come out blurry/tearing. The first 2 pics on http://azngirls.com show the problem im facing atm.

Comment: There's a plugin called [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/). When compressing animated GIFs and creating the thumbnails will retain the animation.
Proof: [Original Image](https://cdromance.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/5543screenshot4.gif). The animated [150x150 thumbnail](https://cdromance.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/5543screenshot4-150x150.gif).